# Lavaan - CFA - categorical variables - the last threshold is strange

Tags: r, categorical-data, r-lavaan

I want to perform a multiple group CFA with `lavaan` in `R`.

I have several categorical variables and some variables contains 11 categories. So these variables will have 10 thresholds. In the results below you can see thatthe 10th threshold is smaller than the 9th, i.e., it is not in the creasing order.

Several variables with 11 categories have the same problem.

[image: Screen shot with the visual problem (summary)]

## Question:

*Why are the thresholds distorted?*

## R-code:

```
model2<-'range = ~ NA*gvjbevn + gvhlthc + gvslvol + gvslvue + gvcldcr + gvpdlwk

goals = ~ NA*sbprvpv + sbeqsoc + sbcwkfm

range~~1*range

goals~~1*goals

gvhlthc ~~ gvslvol

gvcldcr ~~ gvpdlwk

'

cfa.model2<-cfa(model2, ordered=varcat, estimator="WLSMV",data=sub)

summary(cfa.model2,fit.measures=TRUE,standardized=TRUE, modindices=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Label assignation of the thresholds was sorted alphabetically, aka `c('t1','t10','t2','t3'....)` but `summary()` sorts it ""properly"".

You can try to add additional factors to check if your scale corresponds to:

```
c('t1','t10','t11','t12',...,'t2','t3'....)
```

Not much you can do on your side, except understand which row is each of your factors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like I cannot add a comment due to not having enough reputation, so I can only reply with an answer, although this is not a proper answer (it will definitely not solve your issue, though I hope it points in the right direction).

For your example to be reproducible, you should provide the community with the data to fit the model.

On the other side, I guess your problem must have to do with the nature of the category: it's possible that your 11th category does not mean "the most level of agreement" with the item, or that the response categories are not ordered from 1 to 11, or something similar.  Given that the rest of the thresholds seem to accurately represent a continuous, monotonically increasing scale, and that this same problem precisely happens in the same category in different variables (at least the two that you are showing), there must be something with the response scale in those items.

In summary, it seems to be more of a problem of interpretation of the parameters of the model rather than a statistical issue.